# Issues using word-wrap: break-word and overflow-wrap: break-word

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I have spent almost two days figuring out why my `li` element doesn't break the line if it reaches the border. I saw many solutions for a similar issue, but none worked in my case. Could someone take a look at my code? And advise me on any resolution.

```
.main_nav {
  height: 40px;
  ul {
    li:first-child {
      border-top: none;
    }
  }
  .qk-dropdown_menu { // TODO: modify after removing bootstrap
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: 100% !important;
    left: 0 !important;
    right: 0;
    transform: none !important;
    width: 90vw;
    padding: 0 !important;
    a, .menu-text {
      line-height: 30px;
      padding: 4px 10px;
      height: 44px;
    }
    #hover_blank {
      line-height: 30px;
      padding: 4px 10px;
      height: 44px;
      .text {
        @include text-in-lines(1);
        display: inline;
      }
    }
    .text { @include text-in-lines(1); }
  }
  .qk-dropdown--third {
    width: fit-content;
    .link_shelf_second {
      max-height: 50vh;
      width: 240px;
    }
    .link_shelf_third {
      width: 240px;
      max-height: 50vh;
      display: none;
      z-index: 2000;
      white-space: normal;
      word-wrap: break-word;
      display:inline-block ;
    }
    li:hover > .link_shelf_third { display: block; }
  }
}
```

***I have a ".liquid" file, not regular ".html" file. Please check below:***

```
  <div class="dropdown_menu qk-dropdown_menu dropdown-menu qk-dropdown--third qk-bd--default qk-bd--border qk-bg--nav_menu_bg" role="menu" aria-labelledby="">
    <ul class="link_shelf_second custom-scrollbar custom-scrollbar__always-show">
      {% for link_shelf_second in linklists[link_shelf_top.url].links %}
        {% if link_shelf_second.link_type == 'linklist'%}
          <li class="qk-pos--static qk-bd_t--default qk-bd--border">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="qk-display--bk qk-fs--body qk-text--nav_menu_text qk-text--accent_hover qk-bg--nav_menu_bg qk-text-truncate">
              <span class="text">{{ link_shelf_second.title }}</span>
            </a>
            <ul class="link_shelf_third qk-w--100 qk-bd--default qk-bd--border qk-pos--abs qk-bg--nav_menu_bg custom-scrollbar custom-scrollbar__always-show">
              {% for link_shelf_third in linklists[link_shelf_second.url].links %}
                <li class="qk-bd_t--default qk-bd--border qk-pos--static">
                  <a href="{{ link_shelf_third.url }}" class="qk-display--bk qk-fs--body qk-text--nav_menu_text qk-text--accent_hover qk-bg--nav_menu_bg qk-text-truncate">
                    <span class="text">{{ link_shelf_third.title }}</span>
                  </a>
                </li>
              {% endfor %}
            </ul>
          </li>
        {% else %}
          <li class="qk-pos--static qk-bd_t--default qk-bd--border">
            <a href="{{ link_shelf_second.url }}" class="qk-display--bk qk-fs--body qk-text--nav_menu_text qk-text--accent_hover qk-bg--nav_menu_bg qk-text-truncate">
              <span class="text">{{ link_shelf_second.title }}</span>
            </a>
          </li>
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Please take a look at the `.link_shelf_third` class. Any help would be appreciated.

***HTML file which was extracted from Chrome dev tools.***

```
<li class="dropdown ">
          <span data-hover="dropdown" class="dropdown_toggle text qk-display--bk qk-fs--body qk-text--nav_menu_text qk-text--accent_hover qk-cursor--pointer">
            WOMAN
          </span>

        <div class="dropdown_menu qk-dropdown_menu dropdown-menu qk-dropdown--third qk-bd--default qk-bd--border qk-bg--nav_menu_bg" role="menu" aria-labelledby="">
          <ul class="link_shelf_second custom-scrollbar custom-scrollbar__always-show">
            
              <li class="qk-pos--static qk-bd_t--default qk-bd--border">
                
                  <a href="/" class="qk-display--bk qk-fs--body qk-text--nav_menu_text qk-text--accent_hover qk-bg--nav_menu_bg qk-text-truncate">
                    <span class="text">Layer 2 TestMe 1 TestMe2 </span>
                  </a>
              
                  <ul class="link_shelf_third qk-w--100 qk-bd--default qk-bd--border qk-pos--abs qk-bg--nav_menu_bg custom-scrollbar custom-scrollbar__always-show" style="top: -2.5e-07px; left: 240px;">
                    
                      <li class="qk-bd_t--default qk-bd--border qk-pos--static">
                        
                          <a href="/" class="qk-display--bk qk-fs--body qk-text--nav_menu_text qk-text--accent_hover qk-bg--nav_menu_bg qk-text-truncate">
                            <span class="text">Layer 3 Layer 3 TestMe1 TestMe2 TestMe3</span>
                          </a>

                      </li>
                      
                  </ul>

              </li>

          </ul>
        </div>
</li>
```

I want the line to break and start from a new line instead of being hidden when it reaches the border.
I checked/tested a lot of StackOverflow solutions, but none of them worked.

Comment: Could you post some of your HTML as well, that would help us figure out your issue.

Comment: CSS without any HTML it is supposed to apply to, tells us rather little. Please always present a proper [mre], when asking questions like this.

Comment: @CBroe pls check html part, I updated it. Please check it.

Comment: @erecodes pls check html part, I updated it. Please check it.

Comment: That is still some sort of templating syntax, but we lack the data behind it, to reproduce your exact output. Please show the actual, resulting HTML.

Comment: @CBroe pls take a look

Comment: This is what we can reproduce, with the code you have given us so far: https://jsfiddle.net/sh8f67py/ - I don't see what the issue is supposed to be with that.